# Cypress/Javascript - Trying to click on a button that is not already selected

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am having issue in my cypress where I am trying to click on a second button that is not disabled or selected already. What is happening currently is that it is selecting the already selected button and I am not sure why this is.

Here is a html example, so if you look at the code below, there are two divs which each handle a selection row. Within each row is a button (`<a>` link).

So what happens is that if a button is selected, the class `selected` is added onto the `<a> element like so`:

```
<a id="event-selection-4191929065" eventid="event-selection-19976412" title="Ronaldo to score 2 or more goals" eventmodule="ODDS_BOOSTS_HOMEPAGE" class="oddsBoostedPrice   button__bet eventSelection--link selected" "="">
```

That's why I have the check to make sure we go through each odds button element and if it does not contain the `.selected` class.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: So if a button is selected then will it be disabled as well ?

Comment: Hey Alapan, no  a button on a website may have been already selected OR there may be buttons that are already disabled (like if a match is in progress, some odds buttons may be disabled). A button cannot be both selected and disabled.

Comment: Do you have any class that would be present at all times irrespective the button is selected or disabled ?

Comment: yes that will be the `.button__bet` class as provided above

Comment: If you want to check yourself, if you go to https://www.pokerstarssports.uk/ and then click on any odds button under odds boost table as an example and you can see what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one can be simplified, because you already check class `.button__bet` inside `oddsButton` method.

```js
oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton()
  .each((element, index) => {
    if (!element.hasClass("disabled") && !element.hasClass("selected")) {
      cy.wrap(element).click()
      return false
    }
  })
```

Sorry, it needs `&&` between the two class checks because each check is `!` (not).

---

`disabled` is usually an attribute, which would be checked like this

```js
oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton()
  .each((element, index) => {
    if (!element.attr("disabled") && !element.hasClass("selected")) {
      cy.wrap(element).click()
      return false
    }
  })
```

Tested with this HTML fragment

```html
<button class="oddsBoostedPrice   button__bet eventSelection--link selected"></button>
<button class="oddsBoostedPrice   button__bet eventSelection--link" disabled></button>
<button class="oddsBoostedPrice   button__bet eventSelection--link"></button>
```

Only the 3rd button passes into the `if()` statement.

Comment: Hey Mihi, thanks for your suggestion. Sadly it is still selecting the already selected button

Comment: It works ok on my test with two buttons one with class `selected` and one without. The `disabled` looks suspicious - is that a class? Usually it's an attribute. Will add 2nd block for disabled attribute.

Comment: Your right Mihi, it's the disabled attibute causing the issue. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing your if condition to something like this:

```js
oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().each((element, index) => {
  if (!element.prop("disabled") && !element.hasClass("selected")) {
    cy.wrap(element).click()
    return false
  }
})
```